# How can I use my iSight camera as an IP camera?

Tags: macos, mac, webcam, localhost

Is there any kind of software that can convert the built-in `iSight` camera on a Mac OS X into an IP camera and serving it to a `localhost`? Preferably as static images, but any kind of stream is also accepted.

Comment: Is this the built in iSight on your Mac, or the old now unavailable external iSight?

Comment: @Chealion It's a built-in camera.. I updated my question to reflect that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in just pictures every x minutes, you could roll your own script or use a program such as [EyeSight](http://www.klieme.com/EyeSight.html). Just put the latest picture into your `~/Sites` folder, and navigate to `http://localhost/~username/NAME_OF_PICTURE.jpg`

If you're looking at wanting to send actual video, you may want to look at [QuickTime Broadcaster](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL764) from Apple. It's not very easy to use but it does work.

Comment: I'm not interesting in the actual video.. just static pictures..! So EyeSight will definitely work for me..! But you also said something about my own script.. can I grab an image via command line without downloading anything? Does MacOS supports that by default? (I'm using 10.6) I would prefer that actually because I'm writing an application for cameras in general :D

Comment: With a quick search I found a command line tool, called iSightCapture that does it.. so for now I'm more than covered for what I want.. and maybe at one point I'll ask something more specific on SO if I run into troubles.. :) Thank you..

Comment: Unfortunately I'm too noob here.. so I can't even upvote yet..!

Comment: @Lipis: FYI: Upvote is the up arrow above the number beside an answer. The checkmark is for marking a question as the answer.